# I need a program that shows always on top Youtube CC

Tags: gratis, closed-captions, macos-catalina

I like listening to Youtube Videos while doing other things but I also like knowing what the song that I'm listening to is saying but to do that, I would have to get a version with the lyrics in the video then use the mini-player which covers part of my screen and is hard to read on.

What I want is a program that will make the built-in YT captions on top of every window or get the captions of the video and make an always-on-top window with the captions in them. I want one that's free, Runs on macOS Catalina, and I don't care what the license is. (Preferably with a transparent background behind the text.) I haven't been able to find any software like this so that's why I'm asking here.

**Thank you!**

---

TLDR; I need a program that can show YT Closed Captions on top of every window that is free and runs on macOS Catalina.

Comment: Bump because I still don't have anything to so this for me.

Comment: Is there anything that could do this?

Comment: I've updated to Big Sur, and I still have nothing.